# Conditional label expression gives error in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, labeling

I have a polygon dataset and I would like to label the area of all polygons which have `"kamer"` in the column `"type"`.

I tried some expressions but I get different Errors.
Two examples of what I tried is the following:

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [Area], [type] )
  if ([type] = 'kamer') then
   FindLabel = UCase([Area])
  end if
End Function
```

This gives me the following error:

> The expression contains an error.
>  
>     Modify the expression and try again.
>     Error 1 on line 16.
>     Syntaxisfout.

Another expression I tried is:

```vb
def FindLabel ([Soort_kamer], [Oppervlakte]):
  if int([Soort_kamer]) = 'kamer':
    return [Oppervlakte]
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. If you say "I tried something" please make sure to include your trials in your question.

Comment: Could you also add to your question what goes wrong. *Can't get it to work* is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double quotes in your if statement

```vb
Function FindLabel ([Area], [type])
  if ([type] = "kamer") then
    FindLabel = UCase([Area])
  end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this line of the Python version:

```
if int([Soort_kamer]) = 'kamer':
```

Firstly, it is comparing an integer to with a string.  Secondly it is using the assignment operator (single `=`) not the equality comparator (double `==`).

Assuming the 'Soort_kamer' field is actually a string field, that line should be:

```
if [Soort_kamer] == 'kamer':
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the int in this code, I fixed it now and used the equalty comparator